# Query SQL columns

Tags: sql

I have this:

```
Id     Store        Situation   Total
1      Store 1      Credit       10
2      Store 1      No credit    20
3      Store 3      Credit       50
4      Store 3      No credit    80
```

I want this:

```
Num    Store     Credit   No_credit
1      Store 1    10         20
2      Store 3    50         80
```

Is possible this?

Thanks.

Comment: please format your results accordingly

Comment: this is fairly simple and want you to answer it for yourself.. hint is,  get the sum of the group by store and situation and then combine to display one row each group;

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just conditional aggregation:

```
select store,
       sum(case when situation = 'Credit' then total else 0 end) as Credit,
       sum(case when situation = 'No Credit' then total else 0 end) as NoCredit,
from t
group by store;
```

You can also add an `id`.  Here is a method that works in most databases:

```
select row_number() over (order by store) as id,
       store,
       sum(case when situation = 'Credit' then total else 0 end) as Credit,
       sum(case when situation = 'No Credit' then total else 0 end) as NoCredit,
from t
group by store
order by store;
```